# Python: Trimming underscores from end of String

Tags: python, arrays

**Hi everyone!** I am trying to debug someones code and I have found the problem. The program loops through an array of strings and count's certain ends. The problem is that some of these strings end with `_`, so the counting goes wrong. I would like to use regex, but I am not experienced enough. Could someone help me?

I would like to loop through the array and per string check if it ends with `_`('s) and trim all of these `_` off to put them again in the array!

**Update**

Thanks for the `rstrip` suggestion! I have tried to write a code that works with my data, but no luck yet...

```
data_trimmed = []
        for x in data:
            x.rstrip('_')
            data_trimmed.append(x)

        print(data_trimmed)
```

But this still returns: `['Anna__67_______', 'Dyogo_3__', 'Kiki_P1_', 'BEN_40001__', .... ]`

Comment: You can do `rstrip('_')` to remove trailing underscores so `some_string.rstrip('_')`

Comment: Will this remove all `_`'s in the string or just at the end?

Comment: Just at the end, try it: `'__as_das___'.rstrip('_')`

Comment: What Ed said. There's no need to bother testing for trailing underscores, just call [`.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) on every line. It can test for the specified chars at C speed faster than you can do it with an explicit Python test.

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to modify all strings in your list, see my updated answer

Comment: `x.rstrip('_')` doesn't modify `x`: Python strings are _immutable_, so string methods can't modify the original, they have to return a new string. On a related note, please see [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29604031/4014959) by abarnert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rstrip('_')` to remove trailing underscores:

```
In [15]:
'__as_das___'.rstrip('_')

Out[15]:
'__as_das'
```

So you can see that any leading underscores and any in the middle of the string are unaffected, see the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions

To answer your updated question you can use a list comprehension to update each string in the list:

```
In [18]:
a = ['Anna__67_______', 'Dyogo_3__', 'Kiki_P1_', 'BEN_40001__']
a = [x.rstrip('_') for x in a]
a

Out[18]:
['Anna__67', 'Dyogo_3', 'Kiki_P1', 'BEN_40001']
```

Comment: I have tried this code: `data_trimmed = [] for x in data:       x.rstrip('_') data_trimmed.append(x)` but it isn't working for me :-(

Comment: it should be s_trimmed.append(x.rstrip('_'))

Comment: @AnnaJeanine You need to reinitialize the value to `x` as `x = x.rstrip('_') `. You may also write this entire logic as: `data_trimmed = [x.rstrip('_') for x in data]`

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you very much for your quick and easy answer!

Answer (score 4):

use string rstrip method to strip off unwanted `_`

```
s = 'anything__'
s = s.rstrip('_') # s becomes 'anything'
```

regex is a bit overkill for this, it can be done as below

```
import re
s = 'anything__'
s = re.sub('_+$', '', s)  # s becomes 'anything'
```